# How can one block downloading media from my server by other web-pages?

Tags: nginx, cors, cross-origin-resource-policy, fetch-metadata, resource-isolation

I have a web-site with images stored on my own server. Some other web-sites use links to these images on their pages, so the server have to handle extra traffic. Can I forbid loading images and other media for external sites with Nginx config? Maybe CORS settings could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

CORS cannot help you there, because CORS doesn't apply to `image` tags that lack a `crossorigin` attribute. You have two options:

- a cross-origin resource policy, or
- a resource isolation policy.

### Cross-origin resource policy

You can specify a [cross-origin resource policy (CORP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)) in the response to requests to your resources. For instance, if you specify the following response header,

```http
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site
```

[browsers that support CORP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)#browser_compatibility) will prevent [cross-site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Site) origins from embedding your resources in their pages.

Two caveats:

- A CORP won't allow you to save any bandwidth, because all browsers (whether or not they support CORP) will download the whole resource first before deciding whether a page can load it.
- The [`Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy) won't have any effect in [browsers that don't support CORP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)#browser_compatibility); users of those browsers will be able to load your resources regardless of the page's origin.

### Resource Isolation Policy

Alternatively, you can implement some [resource isolation policy](https://web.dev/fetch-metadata/#implementing-a-resource-isolation-policy) on the server side via [Fetch Metadata request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Fetch_metadata_request_header):

> A Resource Isolation Policy prevents your resources from being requested by external websites.

Be aware that only modern versions of Chromium-based browsers and ([more recently](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/07/12/firefox-90-supports-fetch-metadata-request-headers/)) Firefox currently send those request headers; Safari notably does not.

However, implementing such a resource isolation policy may be enough to dissuade third parties from embedding your images on their websites, as a large proportion of their visitors won't be able to load your content.