# Only allow calls to an Express+Node app endpoint made by AJAX from pages rendered by that app

Tags: node.js, express

I have a web app built with node.js and express.js. This app renders pages (let's say `[host]/homepage`) but also has some API endpoints (let's say `[host]/api/getinfo`).

The web app will be publicly facing, but I want the API endpoints to only be callable via an AJAX call from the webapp's rendered pages. So in this example, anyone can access `[host]/homepage`, which renders a page that (after some user input) makes an AJAX request to `[host]/api/getinfo`, but people shouldn't be able to query `[host]/api/getinfo` directly (from their browser / postman / other)

What is the best way to achieve this?

I've tried a simple middleware that checks `req.get('origin')`, but this can easily be spoofed.

I suspect there's an obvious answer to this question that I'm missing based on my limited understanding of CORS.

Comment: The obvious answer being: you can't.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004665/how-to-reject-http-https-request-if-not-coming-from-allowed-website-or-source

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047838/how-can-one-block-downloading-media-from-my-server-by-other-web-pages/70048201#70048201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who commented. The basic answer is: this isn't possible.

[How to reject http/https request if not coming from allowed website or source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004665/how-to-reject-http-https-request-if-not-coming-from-allowed-website-or-source) explains why

[How can one block downloading media from my server by other web-pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047838/how-can-one-block-downloading-media-from-my-server-by-other-web-pages/70048201#70048201) provides a solution that will work for a subset of cases.

Comment: I'd say: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004665/how-to-reject-http-https-request-if-not-coming-from-allowed-website-or-source explains how to achieve the desired effect by logging users on.